# Is it possible to search multiple columns from multiple tables by using variables for references?

Tags: sql, ssms

I am using a search algorithm to find tables in my database that meet certain criteria. The output looks like this:

```
TableName     |     ColumnName
--------------+---------------
Table1        |     Column1
Table1        |     Column2
Table1        |     Column3
Table2        |     Column4
Table2        |     Column1
...           |     ...
Table652      |     Column873
```

I then try to use that table as input for another query where I attempted to use either:

```
WHERE Tablename.ColumnName LIKE 'Post 2013 - %'
```

Or

```
WHERE ((TableName).(ColumnName)) LIKE 'Post 2013 - %'
```

Or

```
SELECT ...
CONCAT(TableName, '.', ColumnName) AS TabCol
FROM search
WHERE TabCol LIKE 'Post 2013 - %'
```

The problem is that my code is returning errors at each of these WHERE statements. Is it possible for me to use the first output as a way to scan through those tables for a specific value, returning the TableName and ColumnName where it found the value?

Comment: Presumably, you need dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

To do something like that there are generally two methods that I have found that work.  One is to extract the entire database to text file and use a text searching tool for the data you seek.

The other is to use the system tables to identify all the tabels / fields.  Then have some code loop through those fields running your query.  You may want to check the data type first to eliminate things like date, numeric or integer data types.  Or you could do this manually.  But there is not really as standard Sql way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If your using SQL Server as Database :- You can use dynamic queries.

you can write a stored procedure or Function which has logic similar to that in the screenshot which return table data which the desired results. And you can pass Tablename , Columnname, Conditions as the  parameters . Assuming you have all the data in the table.

[image]

Here is a sample query i tried with above scenario.

```
select * from search;
select * from table2;
Declare @sql varchar(max)
select  @sql='select * from '+ tablename+' where '+columname+'='+'''john-her'''
 from search  where tablename='table2' and columname='namedata2'
select @sql
exec(@sql)
```

I just tried with sample ...there may be multiple scenario with conditions. Hope this helps you in giving you an idea how to solve your problem!!

Comment: At least `QUOTENAME(tablename)` and `QUOTENAME(columname)` please. You don't know what values those variables are storing. Also please take a look at `sp_executesql` when it comes to dynamic SQL.

Comment: Yeah you can use those but i just gave quick sample. I am not sure whether DBMS is sql server or not. I just want to give an idea about how to go about the problem. Anyways thanks for those comments

Comment: You can -> You should. Makes the code safer by preventing some sql injection attack vectors. Even if it is just querying metadata, the query can be syntactically wrong without them. When for example a table's name is `transacton` or any reserved word which has to be quoted.

Comment: Got it !!  @Pred